# How many apples? Updating these unique database entries in PHP at once

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database: 'example_DB' with a customer info table: 'custinfo_tb' and customer attributes table:
'custatt_tb'.

custinfo_tb has collumns:

```
cust_id 
name 
apples
```

Where apples is the number of apples each customer has!

custatt_tb has collumns:

```
cust_id 
age
allowance
favcolor
```

Now, I'm trying to develop code in PHP that determines the number of apples a customer recieves. This is dependent on their age and allowance.  But only customers with a certain favourite color are given apples.

For example:
Jon has 3 apples already and customer ID 1. His allowance is $25 and his favorite color is blue
Jasmine has 12 apples already and customer ID 2. Her allowance is $10 and his favorite color is red
Connor has 2 apples already and customer ID 3. His allowance is $22 and his favorite color is green
Richard has 8 apples already and customer ID 4. His allowance is $30 and his favorite color is red
Everyone is 12 years old.

What is the code I need to update both tables such that:
Any customer who likes the color red gets more apples. The number of apples they get is 
number of apples = Age * Allowance
In the case above, Jasmine will finish with 132 apples and Richard will finish with 368 apples.

This is an odd question i know, but for privacy reasons, I'm substituting the actual code for apples and such! The problem is the same.
Thanks for any help! I have a feeling that i need FOREACH statements inside other FOREACH statements but i can't get it to work. Thanks.

EDIT: This is what I have so far

```
$con=mysqli_connect("private","private","private","example_DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

session_start();



$color = $_POST["colorpicked"];
$age = $_POST["age"];


$getallowance = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT allowance FROM custatt_tb WHERE favcolor = '$color'");
$allowance= mysqli_fetch_array($getallowance);

foreach ($allowance as &$value) {

    $applesgiven= ($value * $age);
    $getnames = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT cust_id FROM custatt_tb WHERE favcolor= '$color' AND allowance = '$value'");
    $getnames2 = mysqli_fetch_array($getnames); 
    foreach ($getnames2 as &$value2 ) {

        $getapples = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT apples FROM custinfo_tb WHERE cust_id = '$value2'");
        $getapples2 = mysqli_fetch_array($getapples);
        $applesold = $getapples2['apples'];
        $applesnew = ($applesold + $applesgiven);

    if (!mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE custinfo_tb SET apples = '$applesnew' WHERE cust_id = '$value2'")) {
        // die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        //  }

    }
}
```

Comment: always show your code what you've tried so far,so that we'll be in better position to anwer

Comment: [little bobby tables... sql injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to hit database multiple times, you can do it all in one pure SQL query

```sql
UPDATE custinfo_tb c JOIN custatt_tb a
    ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
   SET apples = apples + allowance * age
 WHERE a.favcolor = 'red';
```

Outcome:

```
| CUST_ID |    NAME | APPLES |
|---------|---------|--------|
|       1 |     Jon |      3 |
|       2 | Jasmine |    132 |
|       3 |  Connor |      2 |
|       4 | Richard |    368 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a80/1)** demo

Comment: Wow, I didn't know SQL could do all this. Ill have to look everything up but it looks good. Thanks.